# How do the error terms in ARMA or MA models actually work?

Tags: time-series, arima

$x_t = c + \theta_{1}x_{t-1} + \phi_1\varepsilon_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$

```
     t X
[1,] 1 44
[2,] 2 55
[3,] 3 66
[4,] 4 77
```

I want to predict $x_5$. How should the equation be like?
lets say $c = 5$ and $\theta_{1}=2$ and $\phi_1=3$
I am sure that $x_{t-1}$ is 77 but the part that confuses me is $\varepsilon_{t-1}$!
Should we predict the $x_{t-1}$ to calculated its error/residual first? If that's the case then How we can calculate $x_1$ (the first data point at time 1)?
PS. i know the $x_t$ is not stationary. It's just an example.